# How to represent an optional Bool (Bool?) in Objective-C?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a protocol in swift

```
@objc protocol RestAPIManagerDelegate {

      optional func credentialValidated(isValid: Bool?)
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
'Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. Do you want to make a protocol in Swift? If so, why do you need the `@objc`? If you are just wanting to make a protocol in Swift, you can drop the `@objc`

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Then I have to implement all method from this 'RestAPIManagerDelegate'. I want to implement that is needed. So I have to add '@obj c' mark.

Comment: You are implementing this in objective-c and not swift then?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger It is in swift.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is this type declaration:

```
`isValid: Bool?`
```

That is perfectly fine *in Swift*. But you cannot expose it to Objective-C, because Objective-C does not have any notion of an Optional BOOL - a BOOL in Objective-C is basically just a number, a primitive C datatype (what we call a *scalar*).

Here's another way of looking at it. In an interchange with Objective-C, you can use a Swift Optional anywhere that Objective-C can say `nil` - indeed, to a large extent Swift Optional exists exactly in order to deal with the possibility that Objective-C *will* say `nil` or that you might need to say `nil` to Objective-C. But a BOOL in Objective-C can never be `nil` - it can only be YES or NO (Swift `true` or `false`).

So you have three choices:

- Take away the `@objc` that exposes all this to Objective-C
- Remove the Optional and just declare that type a Bool
- Use an object type. For example, declare the type as `AnyObject?` (or `NSNumber?`). This will work because Swift will bridge a Bool to an NSNumber (including as it passes into an AnyObject), and Objective-C will deal just fine with an Optional AnyObject or Optional NSNumber because those are object types, not scalars.

Comment: But one of the answer said they got it working as '@objc protocol RestAPIManagerDelegate {
    optional func credentialValidated(isValid: Bool?)
}'

Comment: @Md.NajmulHasan Not everything everybody says on Stack Overflow is right. :)

Comment: Thanks! I used AnyObject? and it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 4):

Object-C does not have the concept of optionals, try to remove the "?" from your declaration

Comment: But I can write 'optional func messageSourcesReceived(sources:[MessageSourceModel]?)' with no error.

Comment: I have a guess. See if it seems logical. Bool is a primitive type. So can not be 'nil' but custom objects can be 'nil'. So 'Bool?' will not be possible.

Comment: I am very confuse to be honest, I am trying to figure out here

Comment: Bool? is supported. You must not have posted your entire `protocol`. If you have other Types used in the protocol that are not @objc then you will receive that compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to use `NSNumber?` instead, but there is another way.
You can create `OptionalBool` enum and use it instead of `Bool?` for compatibility with Objective-C.

Creating `OptionalBool` enum in Swift code:

```
@objc enum OptionalBool: Int {
    case none
    case yes
    case no
}

@objc protocol RestAPIManagerDelegate {

    @objc optional func credentialValidated(isValid: OptionalBool)
    
}
```

Using `OptionalBool` in Objective-C code:

```
@interface RestAPIManagerHandler () <RestAPIManagerDelegate>
@end

@implementation RestAPIManagerHandler

- (void)credentialValidatedWithIsValid:(enum OptionalBool)isValid {
    switch (isValid) {
        case OptionalBoolYes:
            NSLog(@"TRUE");
            break;
            
        case OptionalBoolNo:
            NSLog(@"FALSE");
            break;
            
        case OptionalBoolNone:
            NSLog(@"NULL");
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift Bool are converted in NSNumber so for example if a Swift method returns `[Bool]` and if you receive this array in Objective-C code, it become a `NSArray <NSNumber *>`. And if you give this array to a Swift method which receives a `[Bool]` as parameter, the conversion will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to just do a protocol in Swift, for use within Swift, without optionals you can do this:

```
public protocol Note {
    var content: [ContentType] {get}

    func insertNote(note: Note) -> Bool
}
```

That will force a class to implement a method that returns a `Bool` and have an array of some class called `ContentType`.

If you want to make the method optional, you must specify the `objc` keyword as you have done, regardless if you are interoperating with Objective-C or not. At that point, everything else should work in your example.

```
@objc protocol RestAPIManagerDelegate {
    optional func credentialValidated(isValid: Bool?)
}
```

From [Apples documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)

> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute.
>
> This attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to Objective-C code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C. Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to specify optional requirements.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply that protocol to class types.

The example given by Apple:

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
    optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}
```

Comment: I just replaced my existing implementation with just your given code. Still error. '@objc protocol RestAPIManagerDelegate {
    optional func credentialValidated(isValid: Bool?)
}'

Comment: Odd. This compiles fine on my machine.

Comment: My Xcode version is 6.3 (6D570). Can I know yours please?

Comment: Mine is 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: I updated my post with a link to Apple's documentation showing basically the same example I provided. It demonstrates it being used exactly as your source code shows. Perhaps try updating your Xcode and Swift

Comment: hmm I have to try. Agree with you.